"Clearance received" annotation on US visas - how long is the clearance valid for?
I  interviewed for a B1/B2 US visa in late June 2023, and was issued a 221(g) form in seconds. My passport spent months in "administrative processing", and the visa was not issued until Sep 11 2023. The visa is valid only up to Aug 23 2024, whereas most of my compatriots would get 10-year visas. It is annotated with
CLEARANCE RECEIVED 23-AUG-2023

Anecdotes suggest this clearance expires in one year, and if I renew the visa before this clearance expires, I will only have to wait for days rather than months. I am about to renew this visa without attempting an interview waiver, and the earliest interview opportunity I can get is on Aug 22 2024. I expect to leave the country soon after September. Therefore, it is of utmost importance for me to know whether the clearance will expire on Aug 23 2024 or Aug 22 (i.e. after 365 days), and whether I should spend considerable time and effort looking for slots earlier than Aug 22. This is complicated by the fact that there are 366 days between Aug 23 2023 and Aug 23 2024.

US giving you a shorter visa is strange (if the other people had same citizenship): US policy is: you trust, so maximum for the country, or not trust and so deny. So your question is difficult (and it seems you do not know the reason, so possibly impossible to answer)
